# MySql Workbench: can the path to mysqldump Tool be inside a docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to dump the contents of a remote db to my local macos machine after upgrading my remote db and local docker-container db from 5.6 to 8. The issue is that I don't know how to configure mysql workbench to use the docker mysqldump tool for this purpose as it is currently using a local 5.6 installation:

[image]

Is it possible, or do I need a local installation of mysql 8 for this to work?

Comment: why not use mysql workbench migration, when you can connect to the database in the container you can copy anything

Comment: It's never worked for me. However, I was always using it with 5.6 dbs so I should try with 8.x